# Unable to catch the exception in try/catch statement in powershell

Tags: powershell, exception, error-handling

I am trying to catch the exception in an `if` statement - but `catch` not throwing any exception even if the condition is failed

I have below condition where I am trying to check if the size of files is `-gt` than the given `N` number. The `try` part is executing if the condition is valid, but the catch part not throwing any error even if the condition is wrong

```bsh
$source_dir="C:\test_files_arch"
$Existing_count_of_files=Get-ChildItem $source_dir | Measure-Object | Select-Object Count
$existing_files= ls $source_dir
$Expected_count_of_file=5

#Assuming the Existing_count_of_files is 4, so it should failed

try {
    if($count_of_files.Count -gt $Expected_count_of_file) {
        $existing_files
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Error "Number of file is less"
}
```

I need to get the Expected catch statement for all failure cases. I tried with many ways to get the catch exception, but nothing is working.

Appreciate if any one can help on this.

Comment: the TRY/CATCH/FINALLY stuff requires - **_requires_** - a terminating error. you don't have anything at all that will trigger such an error in any part of your code - and it MUST be in the `try` section. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you @Lee_Dailey . That got worked after i include the finally statement

Comment: you are welcome [*grin*] ... but you are not using the try/catch/finally correctly, tho. [*frown*] you are NOT catching any errors. you are simply adding meaningless code that runs the `try` and then the `finally` blocks and has _no error handling at all_. as it stands, you have a very strange scriptblock. i would totally remove the meaningless code OR rewrite it to actually do error handling.

Answer (score 2):

As Lee_Dailey mentioned in the comments, the `catch` block only ever executes when it "catches" an exception (or, in PowerShell, a *terminating* error) thrown from inside the preceding `try` block.

A comparison statement returning `$false` is *not* an exception - `-gt` is *supposed* to return a boolean answer!

In your case, simply adding an `else` block to the `if` statement would do, `try/catch` doesn't really make much sense:

```bsh
# I changed the operator to `-ge` - aka. >= or "Greater-than-or-Equal-to"
# based on the assumption that `$Expected_count_of_file` is the minimum number expected 
if($count_of_files.Count -ge $Expected_count_of_file) {
    $existing_files
}
else {
    # This only executes if the `if` condition evaluated to `$false`
    Write-Error "Number of file is less"
}
```